# CSS Transition Jumpy / Jerky

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have been using the `scale()` property, which was working fine until a few weeks ago. After the browsers got updated, now I see a jerky/jumpy animation, can someone please point out where exactly my problem is?

Please take a look at the following **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kkpa4v5/)**; in the rollover, the ICON (which is showing "A") will slide in from the bottom and scale at the same time, but it goes down to the starting point creating a jerky/jumpy animation effect.

```css
.ca-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:20px auto;
    width: 1020px;
}
.ca-menu li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-right: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
}
.ca-icon {
    font-family:'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
    line-height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}
.ca-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.ca-main {
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.ca-sub {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 40px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon {
    color: #ff2020;
    -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
    color: #ff2020;
    -webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ff2020;
    -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes smallToBig {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes smallToBig {
    from {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="ca-icon">A</span>
      <div class="ca-content">
        <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
        <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized to your needs</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all the `transition` property from `.ca-icon`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kkpa4v5/2/)

also you need only `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefix for `@keyframes`, the `-ms-` prefix for `@keyframes` doesn't exist, it is considered a good practice to include a unprefixed `@keyrames` also. Although this is not causing the problem, just told you about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is using `transition` and `animation` at the same time on `.ca-icon`.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3kkpa4v5/1/